# Beautiful Soup 4: extracting text only from a tag containing children tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I've got this HTML snippet from a bigger document and I want to scrape the "$ 430000" string from the main `div` with `class="title"` only:

```html
<div class="title">
 $ 430000
 <div class="container">
  <span class="price">
   $ 505000
  </span>
  <span class="discount">
   (-14.9%)
  </span>
  <div class="inner-container">
   <p class="text--bold">
    Discounted $ 75000
    <span class="discount">
     (-14.9%)
    </span>
   </p>
   <p>
    18/02/2010
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I know I could access the desired string through `tag.stripped_strings` and then yielding the first value from the generator:

```py
tag = soup.find('div', {'class': 'title'})
print(next(tag.stripped_strings))
```

```sh
$ 430000
```

However, I am wondering if there is BS4 attribute or method with which I could target the text from the `<div class="title">` only, the "$ 430000" string. If I called `tag.text` I'd get

````sh
\n                    $ 430000\n                                                                    $ 505000(-14.9%)\n                                    Discounted $ 75.000(-14.9%)18/02/2021```
````

Comment: What seems to be the exact problem here? You are already getting the desired output, no?

Comment: @baduker to me it feels like what I'm doing is a hack and I am wondering if there is a more precise way of doing this

Comment: IMHO, this is a pretty straightforward and rather a precise way (you're actually getting what you need, right?). I'd maybe add `strip()` to `print(next(tag.stripped_strings).strip())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for **`.next_element`[[docs]](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-element-and-previous-element)** attribute which points to immediate afterwards of whatever was grabbed. So, in your case, it will look something like this.

```
result = soup.find('div', class_='title').next_element.strip()
# -> $ 430000
```

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the text of only the parent element and ignore the text of its child elements the following way:

```
tag = soup.find('div', {'class': 'title'})
tagtext = tag.find(text=True, recursive=False)
```

Comment: thanks,  this is helpful, however I'd amend your response like this
`tagtext = tag.find(text=True, recursive=False).strip()`
also, I noted that `tagtext = tag.find(text=True).strip()` does the job as well...

Comment: Yes, however I observed that sometimes, if i do not give the recursive=False, it return all of the child text too.